# Vim: inoremap works in buffer, not in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I'm really eager to include the following in my .vimrc file:

```
inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-u>
```

If I set it within a buffer (via `:inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-u>`) it works exactly as I'd hoped.

But, if I place it in my .vimrc, it doesn't seem to be acknowledged at all.

I've attached my .vimrc below. A few things:

- Other changes to the .vimrc file are picked up, so it's not the wrong file
- Have tried adding at the very bottom of the .vimrc & still doesn't work, so it's not being overwritten

Any ideas appreciated. Many thanks.

```
" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Word complete
" :autocmd BufEnter * call DoWordComplete() 
" let g:WC_min_len = 4


" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible
map j gj
map k gk

set showmatch " Show matching brackets
set mat=5 " Bracket blinking
set noerrorbells " No noise

" Ruby autocomplete

" Autocomplete behaviour
set completeopt=longest,menuone
open omni completion menu closing previous if open and opening new menu without changing the text
inoremap <expr> <C-Space> (pumvisible() ? (col('.') > 1 ? '<Esc>i<Right>' : '<Esc>i') : '') .
            \ '<C-x><C-o><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-n>\<lt>C-p>\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
" open user completion menu closing previous if open and opening new menu without changing the text
inoremap <expr> <S-Space> (pumvisible() ? (col('.') > 1 ? '<Esc>i<Right>' : '<Esc>i') : '') .
            \ '<C-x><C-u><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>C-n>\<lt>C-p>\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'


autocmd FileType ruby,eruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
" highlight Pmenu ctermbg=238 gui=bold "improve autocomplete menu color

" Colours
highlight Pmenu ctermfg=6 ctermbg=238 guibg=grey30


" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" if has("vms")
"   set nobackup        " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
" else
"   set backup      " keep a backup file
" endif

" Set backupdir to tmp
" Do not let vim create <filename>~ backup files
set nobackup
" set nowritebackup

set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" Set tab to 2 spaces
set ts=2
set shiftwidth=2

" Ignore case
set ignorecase
set smartcase

" Menu autocomplete
set wildmode=longest,list
set wildmenu

" Call pathogen
call pathogen#infect()

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Turn syntax highlighting on (Added by John Bayne, 18/08/2012)
syntax on

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif

" My customisations
" No backup files
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile

" Whitespace identifier
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=lightgreen
:match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/



" Colour options
" color codeschool
" set guifont=Monaco:h12
" let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
" set guioptions-=T " Removes top toolbar
" set guioptions-=r " Removes right hand scroll bar
" set go-=L " Removes left hand scroll bar
" autocmd User Rails let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>" " displays <% %> correctly
" :set cpoptions+=$ " puts a $ marker for the end of words/lines in cw/c$ commands

" Tab behaviour for ultisnips
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>" 
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>" 
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>" 


inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-u>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, `:scriptnames`, while useful, is not the best way to see where a mapping was last set.

```
:verbose map <tab>
```

is a lot more precise.

Comment: Every time I answer a _Vi_ question, I basically assume that somebody will come along with a better answer real soon.  Thanks!

Comment: That's the main reason I'm hanging around here, actually. The points or whatever they are called are not as valuable as all the stuff I'm learning from trying to answer, reading other people's answers. And getting my butt kicked by ZyX.

Comment: This might be obvious, but you can also use `:verbose imap`, and `:verbose inoremap`, etc. That's what I needed!

Comment: This comment is exactly what I needed to figure out why my `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` imappings weren't working. It showed that another plugin, `vim-latex`, was overriding those keys.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe another script is overwriting it after your *.vimrc* is read.

You can use `:scriptnames` to see what files are read on startup.

Comment: Many thanks - I didn't know about :scriptnames. Adding it to the end of the last called script works. ...Now I just need to narrow it down to where the overwrite is occurring

Comment: In case anyone runs into the same thing: It was the UltiSnips plugin

Comment: @PlankTon - Thanks for asking the question... I didn't know about `:scriptnames` either until just now!  I think it would have saved me a bunch of time in the past.